# Can I have a JSON Schema dependency that adds a field inside an array of objects?

Tags: jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a JSON Schema that includes an array of objects. I'd like one of the fields inside those objects to be dependent on a property outside the array.

I created the following schema:

```
{
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    showNotes: {
      title: "Add notes field",
      type: "boolean",
    },
    choices: {
      type: "array",
      title: "Choices",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          itemName: {
            type: "string",
            title: "Item"
          },
          isRequired: {
            type: "boolean",
            title: "Required?",
            default: false
          },
          note: {}
        }
      },
      default: [
        {
          content: "Thing 1",
          correct: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  dependencies: {
    showNotes: {
      oneOf: [
        {
          properties: {
            showNotes: {
              enum: [
                false
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          properties: {
            showNotes: {
              enum: [
                true
              ]
            },
            note: {
              title: "Note",
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping that the new field `note` would update the one at `items/note`, but it did not, instead it generated a new field `note` at the bottom. This can be seen here:

https://codepen.io/samfentr/pen/ZEQpeyg

I assume that the solution will have something to do with adding `$ref` reference, but I haven't been able to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.

I needed to put the entire path to `notes` in my `oneOf` option:

```
showNotes: {
  oneOf: [
    {
      properties: {
        showNotes: {
          enum: [
            false
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      properties: {
        showNotes: {
          enum: [
            true
          ]
        },
        choices: {
          items: {
            properties: {
              note: {
                type: "string",
                title: "Note"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://codepen.io/samfentr/pen/BajQwYE